# Slow Loading Times for Uncached Pages

Tags: wp-query, cache

I have a job search website, http://www.jobvfx.com, where I’m utilizing both LiteSpeed Cache and Cloudflare to enhance performance. The caching is working effectively, and cached pages load within 2 seconds, thanks to LiteSpeed. FYI, I have implemented the standard caching policy on Cloudflare.

However, I’m encountering an issue with uncached pages, as they are taking anywhere between 10 to 30 seconds to load. To investigate the problem, I have utilized the Query Monitor plugin to check the page load time and running queries. According to the plugin’s data, the query load time is only 1.16 seconds, but the page generation itself takes approximately 12 seconds.

I have also monitored the resource usage through my hosting provider’s interface, and nothing unusual is evident in terms of resource consumption.

[image]

**Example uncached URL:**
https://jobvfx.com/job/production-coordinator-39/

**Cached URL:**
https://jobvfx.com/job/2d-artist-32/

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue with slow loading times for uncached pages on my website.

[image]

Comment: Recommend using [Query Monitor's profiling](https://querymonitor.com/blog/2018/07/profiling-and-logging/) to determine where that time is being spent: you may have some highly inefficient code.

Comment: What are you loading that is 163.1MB?  I looked at the site and there's no really any large images I can see. And 346 queries?